# presentingViewController returns the parent of the actual presenting view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm presenting a view controller (VC3) from a view controller (VC2) that is a child of another view controller (VC1). The `presentingViewController` property of VC3 returns VC1 instead of VC2. Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to access VC2 from VC3 without setting up a property in VC3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`presentingViewController` will be one which is embedded in navigation stack, and vc2 is not in navigation stack and vc1 is in navigation that's why you are getting that. You can access `childViewControllers` of vc1 from which you can get VC2. Or you can keep `weak` reference of vc2 inside vc3 and can use that one as well.

1.[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)
 2.[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense, but I don't remember seeing a mention of the "navigation stack" in the Apple documentation; just "the presented view controller updates its presentingViewController property to point back to the view controller that presented it." Do you have any references?

Comment: This is how it works, if view controller is not presented in navigation stack it will look for its ancestors,

Answer (score 1):

There could few possibilities to get the reference and perform some actions, but still I suggest to use Delegation Pattern - it's the most flexible and clean solution.